# concatenate the result of echo and a command output

Tags: linux, bash, printing, printf, echo

I have the following code:

```
names=$(ls *$1*.txt) 
head -q -n 1 $names | cut -d "_" -f 2
```

where the first line finds and stores all names matching the command line input into a variable called names, and the second grabs the first line in each file (element of the variable names) and outputs the second part of the line based on the "_" delim.

This is all good, however I would like to prepend the filename (stored as lines in the variable names) to the output of cut. I have tried:

```
names=$(ls *$1*.txt) 
head -q -n 1 $names | echo -n "$names" cut -d "_" -f 2
```

however this only prints out the filenames

I have tried

```
names=$(ls *$1*.txt 
head -q -n 1 $names | echo -n "$names"; cut -d "_" -f 2
```

and again I only print out the filenames.

The desired output is:

```
$
filename1.txt <second character>
```

where there is a single whitespace between the filename and the result of cut.

Thank you.

Comment: `echo` doesn't take input from standard input so that pipe isn't doing anything useful for you and that `cut` command should be hanging waiting for input (since you didn't give it any).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Best approach, using awk

You can do this all in one invocation of awk:

```
awk -F_ 'NR==1{print FILENAME, $2; exit}' *"$1"*.txt
```

On the first line of the first file, this prints the filename and the value of the second column, then exits.

---

#### Pure bash solution

I would always recommend against parsing `ls` - instead I would use a loop:

You can avoid the use of `awk` to read the first line of the file by using bash built-in functionality:

```
for i in *"$1"*.txt; do
    IFS=_ read -ra arr <"$i"
    echo "$i ${arr[1]}"
    break
done
```

Here we read the first line of the file into an array, splitting it into pieces on the `_`.

Comment: thanks Tom. yes I see that storing the 1st line into an array gives me access to any element, so I could call multiple elements which might come in handy. also - why avoid using ls?

Comment: You will soon run into problems using `ls`, particularly when file names contain characters such as spaces or `*`. See the links in [Etan's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299046/concatenate-the-result-of-echo-and-a-command-output/29299328#comment46793440_29299333) for more details.

Comment: just one thing - the results stored in array need to be elements of the first line of the file, where your solution reads in the filename. I'll provide output one sec....

Comment: @brucezepplin I didn't realise that was what you wanted to do. I've edited both approaches.

Comment: @brucezepplin no problem, please see my latest update for a much simpler approach.

Comment: that awk oneliner is very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that will satisfy your need **BUT THIS IS BAD CODING** (see comments):

```
#!/bin/bash

names=$(ls *$1*.txt)    
for f in $names
do
  pattern=`head -q -n 1 $f | cut -d "_" -f 2`
  echo "$f $pattern"
done
```

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor for why this suggestion  is using bad practices and see TomFenech's answer for how to write the loop without those problems.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't misunderstand your goal, this also works.

I've always done it this way, I just found out that **this is a deprecated way to do it**.

```
#!/bin/bash

names=$(ls *"$1"*.txt)
for e in $names;
    do echo $e `echo "$e" | cut -c2-2`;
done
```

Comment: Dear downvoter, please tell me why isn't this useful.

Comment: Oh, I see. REDUNDANCY! Fixed.

Comment: There are several things wrong with this approach. Looping through the output of `ls` is never a good idea, for reasons detailed in [Etan's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299046/concatenate-the-result-of-echo-and-a-command-output/29299328#comment46793440_29299333). What if a file name contains spaces? Also, you should quote your variables `$1` and `$e`.

Comment: I was reading that article just after editing this post. I get your point. Anyway, I'll leave this approach here as the bad example, and take note about what @Etan said, due to I've always done it this way. I have to make sure I never forget.

Comment: thanks SebasSBM - I flocked straight away to this approach given ls is a go to command for this kind of thing, so having this hear and it's drawbacks would also be useful for anyone trying to do this.